# Regex in LibreOffice Writer - finding "everything" but one thing

Tags: regex, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I have a text (html code) and need to find `<p>` tags with their classes, id, styles (if any) etc. I'm doing this using the following regexs: 
`<p(.*?)>` or `(<p([^>]+))>`

The pattern of my text is here:

```
<p class="navi_buttons">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

<p class="reg">Aliquam mi sapien, rutrum eget sem vel, semper efficitur.<a href="xyz.html" class="topiclink">vitae velit</a></p>

<p class="THIS_SHOULD_BE_AVOIDED">Donec fringilla sapien vitae interdum volutpat.</p>

<p class="nav">Cras nec orci non dolor ultrices luctus sit amet vitae velit.</p>
```

The problem is that I need to find every occurrence of `<p>` tag except one certain class (i.e. I want to avoid paragraphs of this class). I don't know how to write an exclusion that is treated as a string, not a set of the individual characters. I would appreciate your help. Kind regards,

Answer (score 2):

I would cheat rather than try to work out a regex.

Search for the tag you don't want to change, and replace it with a unique string:

```
Search: "<p class="nav">"  Replace: "***xxxxxx***"
```

Then do your operation on all the other `<p>` tags, and reverse the original change:

```
Search: "***xxxxxx***"  Replace: "<p class="nav">"
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Your solution of course will work but it's not exactly what I want to achieve. This regex must be used on dozens of pages, and each page has a different class to be avoided (fortunately names of these classes keep a certain pattern). The job should be done as automatic as possible.

Comment: @gordom Can you give examples of the classes?

Comment: The examples of these classes are: 
`<p class="p_ChapterHeader2">` 
`<p class="f_FooterSWSLogo">` 
The unique name pattern of these all classes is that they all start with one character followed by `_` mark.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be solved. I asked on the forum dedicated to LibreOffice also, and got the answer:

`<p (?!.*EXCLUDING_PATTERN.*)(.*?)>` e.g: `<p (?!.*"THIS.*)(.*?)>`

It works, at least in my case.

Comment: This appears to work, using the example given in an earlier comment: `<p(?! class=\"._)(.*?)>` -- in my test it worked well. Better than the one in the anwer since `<p (?!.` (with the `[space]` *before* the "lookahead") will omit hits on `<p>` also.  Explanation for this technique: "[Lookahead and Lookbehind...](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)"

Comment: You're right. I was conscious about it. But since there is no such tag as "standalone" `<p>` in my docs, I don't mind. On the other hand, there are `<param>` tags that need to be excluded. I'm doing this by putting that `[space]` after p in my regex.